# Flink reads Kafka, consume speed drops dramatically in some case

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink

We have a Flink job (Flink version: 1.9), which joins two kafka sources by key, for each key, start a 5-minutes timer, messages are cached in Flink state, when the timer ends, merge messages with same key (normally, there're 1~5 messages for each key) into a fat one and emit it to kafka.

[image]

Two kafka sources:

1. source1 (160 partitions, 20~30 million messages per minute),
2. source2 (30 partitions, 1~3 million messages per minute).

The flat-map just deserializes the kafka message.

The KeyedProcess is where the timer and Flink state come into play.

I've tried some to improve the performance, e.g. modulo the key to reduce the amount of timers, or increase the hardware (currently 2000c 4000gb), or adjust the parallelism of operators.

Currently the problem is, the consume speed drops dramatically when source1 goes beyond 25 million messages per minute, and never recovers. While it works fine if less than 25 million messages/minute.

The kafka cluster itself seems does not have problem, because there's another system reading from it, and that system does not have any consume speed problem.

Could anyone please shed some light? How to address the cause? Or anything I can try? Is it a good idea to add more hardware (I think 2000c&4000gb is alread a huge amount of resource)? Many thanks.

Comment: How is the state backend configured?

Comment: @DavidAnderson Hi David, I use rocksdb state backend. BTW, checkpoint is disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might start by attaching a profiler to see where the bottleneck is. (Perhaps the disk?)

It seems plausible that at some scale, RocksDB is no longer performing well.
Some tuning might be needed. You should be able to gain some insight by [enabling the RocksDB native metrics](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/config.html#rocksdb-native-metrics) and looking to see how various RocksDB metrics change when the problem occurs.

These are some of the more useful metrics:

```
estimate-live-data-size
estimate-num-keys
num-running-compactions
num-live-versions
estimate-pending-compaction-bytes
num-running-flushes
size-all-mem-tables
block-cache-usage
```

Depending on where and how this workload is running, it's possible that you are hitting some sort of rate limiting or throttling. See [The Impact of Disks on RocksDB State Backend in Flink: A Case Study](https://www.ververica.com/blog/the-impact-of-disks-on-rocksdb-state-backend-in-flink-a-case-study)
 for an interesting example.